# Extracts the element of a tuple by type and ambiguity

Tags: c++, clang, tuples, libc++, iterable-unpacking

[The article](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/get) states that for free `std::get` function overloadings (from 4-6 items) they

> Extracts the element of the tuple t whose type is T. Fails to compile if the tuple has more than one element of that type.

Is the last statement a requirements or just a possibility?

I ask the question because `std::get< int >(std::make_tuple(1, 2))` compiles fine by `clang++ -std=gnu++1z -stdlib=libc++` ([<kbd>live example</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/af1759a3b2261d4a)). Is this tuple's behaviour a *libc++* bug or is one conformant to the Standard?

Comment: there us something worng with your flags. erase everything and simple write an "Hello world" app with the same flags, the console shows nothing

Comment: @DavidHaim > Console shows nothing. It is a good result. Lack of the errors during compilation is good information in the case.

Comment: @DavidHaim I slightly modified the example to print exit status (zero is success).

Answer (score 2):

From the standard §20.4.2.6/8, the requirements are:

> Requires: The type T occurs exactly once in Types.... Otherwise, the program is ill-formed.

So your program is ill-formed.

The standard even provides an example which is very similar to your situation:

```
const tuple<int, const int, double, double> t(1, 2, 3.4, 5.6);
const int &i1 = get<int>(t); // OK. Not ambiguous. i1 == 1
const int &i2 = get<const int>(t); // OK. Not ambiguous. i2 == 2
const double &d = get<double>(t); // ERROR. ill-formed
```

which if you [plug in Clang](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ba7290dcfe3dbf63) compiles.